# Parsing Xml with Sax on Android

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I'm trying to parse an `XML` from a url page. To do so I have used the SAX implementation explained in [this IBM example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/) with the `Adapter` and other changes I got from [this article](http://www.ingeniumblog.net/2012/01/making-a-slick-rss-reader-in-android/). I've also tried to implement an `AsyncTask` to do the parsing and show a `ProgressDialog` but I think this is where my application starts to break down.

I don't really know exactly how to implement the `AsyncTask` into my code, and I believe my poor implementation is causing my app to force close.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
ListView lv1;
ProgressDialog ShowProgress;
public static ArrayList<MangaItem> MangaItemList = new ArrayList<MangaItem>();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    ShowProgress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
            "Loading. Please wait...", true);
    //new loadingTask().execute("http://www.mangapanda.com/alphabetical");
    new loadFeedTask().execute();

    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri
                    .parse(MangaItemList.get(position).getMangaLink()));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}

class loadFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<MangaItem>> {
    private String feedUrl;

    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        lv1.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(MainActivity.this, MangaItemList));
        //new MangaParserTask().execute();
        ShowProgress.dismiss();

    }

    protected ArrayList<MangaItem> doInBackground(String... params) {
        ArrayList<MangaItem> ParsedMangaItemList = new ArrayList<MangaItem>();
        feedUrl = "http://www.mangapanda.com/alphabetical"; 
        FeedParser parser = new SaxFeedParser(feedUrl);
        ParsedMangaItemList = parser.parse();
        for (MangaItem mitem : ParsedMangaItemList) {
            MangaItemList.add(mitem);
        }
        return MangaItemList;
    }


}
}
```

How can I properly use `AsyncTask` so that my parser will return an `ArrayList` that I can then put into an `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: Your  way is correct. What's matter?

Comment: @AVD My app will Force close when I run it. Logcat doesnt give any errors but below `DalvikVM` there are two `AsyncTask` `Thread` and one says "Suspended Runtime exception" next to it. Thats about as much as I got to debug this

Comment: I've found some *unrelated* code,. Have a look at answer-post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improper use of type parameters in subclass (`AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>`). Re-write the `AsyncTask` sub-class.

```
  class loadFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<MangaItem>> {
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<MangaItem> list) {
        lv1.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(MainActivity.this, list));
        ShowProgress.dismiss();
    }
    protected ArrayList<MangaItem> doInBackground(String... params) {
        ArrayList<MangaItem> list=null;
        String feedUrl = "http://www.mangapanda.com/alphabetical"; 
        FeedParser parser = new SaxFeedParser(feedUrl);
        list = parser.parse();
        MangaItemList=list;
        return list;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
try {

        items = new ArrayList<String>();

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        xpp.setInput(new InputStreamReader(
                getUrlData(" url")));

        while (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            Log.i(TAG, "doc started");
            if (xpp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                if (xpp.getName().equals("entry")) {
                    items.add(xpp.getAttributeValue(0));
                }
            }
            xpp.next();

        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Request failed: " + t.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

get url data method

```
public InputStream getUrlData(String url) throws URISyntaxException,
        ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet method = new HttpGet(new URI(url));
    HttpResponse res = client.execute(method);
    return res.getEntity().getContent();
}
```

Comment: This example uses `XmlPullParser` not `SaxParser`. I'll have to re-write the handler for this but I'll try it let. Let you know how it goes.

Comment: Sorry for the noob question but it says "Method getUrlData() is  undefined for type Mainactivity.loadfeedtask"